# Select option from dropdown where value contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown like this

```
<select id="acctDesc" name="acctDesc">
<option value="1~PB1001~10001~0~Sales Glassware">1</option>
<option value="2~PB1002~10002~0~American">2</option>
<option value="3~PB1003~10003~0~Sales Appliance">3</option>
<option value="4~PB1004~10004~0~Sales Spare Parts">4</option>
<option value="5~PB1005~10005~0~Sales ">5</option>
</select>
```

Also

```
<script>
var test="Sales Glassware";
</script>
```

Now I have to select that option from the dropdown where the value of the option contains the above variable value.
Till now I have used jquery filter but to no avail.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$('option[value$="'+test+'"]').prop('selected', true)`

Comment: You can combine answer from marked link with contains selectors: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Use the attribute selector, $ will search for the options that **ends** with your text

```
$('option[value$='+test+']');
```

Use contains comparator with it to find *"the value of the option **contains** the above variable value"*.

```
$('option[value*='+test+']');
```

To select it, simply append the following before the semicolon:

```
.prop('selected',true);
```

**The Answer:**
Thus, though either method will work, the answer to your specific question (select the option that "***contains***" the value) is:

```
$('option[value*='+test+']').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: Should we really answer a dupe?

Comment: @Rajesh the answer in the comment is not exactly as this question answer

Comment: I am aware of it and hence I have already commented with link for *contains selector*. Point is combining it will solve the problem. So should we really answer all the combinations. Also, there must be a proper dupe. I'll search and add link of it.

Comment: @Rajesh if you find it i will close the question

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()` method to split the particular character in the string and it return with array and use `.pop()` method to get the last value in the array.

```js
$('#acctDesc').on('change', function() {
       var val = $(this).val();
       val = val.split('~').pop();
       alert(val)
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="acctDesc" name="acctDesc">
<option value="1~PB1001~10001~0~Sales Glassware">1</option>
<option value="2~PB1002~10002~0~American">2</option>
<option value="3~PB1003~10003~0~Sales Appliance">3</option>
<option value="4~PB1004~10004~0~Sales Spare Parts">4</option>
<option value="5~PB1005~10005~0~Sales ">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can directly use `value~=searchValue`. No need to split and search